# Multiple variations of TKInter fonts

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, fonts, ttk

I am trying to get a better understanding of using fonts in `tkinter` and `ttk`.

My plan is to have two different styles for headings, each with their own font size. I used `nametofont()` to create an instance of the font and then set the size in two different styles:

```py
labelFont = tkinter.font.nametofont('TkTextFont')
labelFont.config(weight='bold')

ttk.Style().configure("TLabel", font=labelFont, size=12)
ttk.Style().configure("heading.TLabel", font=labelFont, size=48)
```

then apply the styles to headings:

```py
heading = ttk.Label(root, text="Heading", style="heading.TLabel")
label = ttk.Label(root, text="Label", style="TLabel")   #   is style redundant?
```

Unfortunately, I don’t get two different sizes, so this is obviously the wrong approach.

I also tried something like this:

```py
labelFont = tkinter.font.nametofont('TkTextFont')
headingFont = tkinter.font.nametofont('TkTextFont')
# etc
```

thinking that I would get two independent instance of the font, but they appear to be the same instance. If they were independent, I could have used `configure()` to give each of them their own font size.

I took this approach because I wanted to use the built-in named font, and use variables to maintain consistency. What is the correct approach to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `.config(size=...)` on the different instances of `Font`:

```py
labelFont = tkinter.font.nametofont('TkTextFont')
labelFont.config(weight='bold', size=12)

# create a clone of labelFont using Font.copy()
headingFont = labelFont.copy()
headingFont.config(size=48)

s = ttk.Style()
s.configure('TLabel', font=labelFont) # apply to all instance of ttk.Label
s.configure('heading.TLabel', font=headingFont, size=96)

heading = ttk.Label(root, text='Heading', style='heading.TLabel')
label = ttk.Label(root, text='Label') # style='TLabel' is not necessary
```

Comment: The thing that fixed it for me is the expression `labelFont.copy()`. I should have known by now that I should have made a clone of the font object. If you’re happy to add that to your answer, I can accept it. Thanks